# jQuery UI sortable - Change axis of single items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, properties, axis, jquery-ui-sortable

is it possible to define the axis property for single items in a sortable list?

My problem is the following:
I have a sortable list that is connected to another list. This is working fine so far. (See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGVeA/))
Now I want to exculde single list items from being dropped into another list.

To achieve this I want to change the axis property of some items.

Thanks for any help.

Regards, Aley